# Can I prevent the screen from scrolling when dragging a vector path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pen-tool

Sometimes, when I'm drawing a vector path with the pen tool, I need to drag the line further than I have screen space, and this makes the screen scroll down, which makes me lose focus on what I'm looking at.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or some way to prevent the screen from automatically scrolling downward (or whatever direction) and just allow me to drag it as far as I want?

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do is if I notice my path is beyond the window I hold `Spacebar` to move my window around without losing the ability to add on to my pen path.  When you hold down `Spacebar` a small hand should appear while it's head down and once you let go the pen tool will come back.

Answer (score 1):

No. Sorry Illustrator provides no feature to prevent scrolling. You may find the **Navigator Panel** helpful however.

Answer (score -1):

I`m having the same problem, maybe this will help:

1. Just deselect your object
2. Zoom out a bit or scroll down
3. Then select `pen tool` again and
4. Continue at the last anchor point